# Emails in Plain text format

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook, outlook-2010

We are observing users outside organization and added as contact, and part of a Distribution list are receiving emails in plain text format.

We are unable to replicate the issue as the users randomly receive emails in plain text format and they are not repetitive all times.

Exchange version 2010
Outlook version 2010

we tried to add the users as contact and edit the properties to always send rich text email, but it didnt work.

i need assistance to find the root of the issue and provide a solution, anticipating any help.

Comment: Recipient MUAs or mailbox servers could be filtering the formatted messages parts for any number of reasons. You would have to log outgoing messages, if MS Exchange allows for it.

Comment: A rule of thumbs, if only some users from that distribution list show that error its most likely an error on their side

Comment: Can you give us more infos, which Version is MS Exchange (which CU) and are you using an AntiSpam or AntiVirus Solution (client and/or Server)? Can you also post an header here from the email received by two users. For one users the email should be ok, for the other one it should be plaintext. Can you also give us infos if you are using S/MIME or PGP?

Comment: Exchange-2010, AV- Symantec, Antispam - Symantec
https://www.screencast.com/t/l8TtaPHse - Header

Comment: its random, at times no one gets plain, at times every one get a plain message, at times few , i am not able to find a relation in this